# How to add scrollbars in menus

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde

Recently I switched to Kubuntu 18.04 and one thing which annoys me is huge menus. You can see the issue in the image below, when an application menu contains more items than it can fit on a screen, the menu is stacked. While I was using Unity those menus were scrollable (they had up/down arrows).
Is it possible that I have up/down arrows in KDE as well?
[image: firefox menu]

Comment: Are the scrollbars missing only in Firefox or other applications as well?

Comment: @DKBose When I use Firefox menu scrollbars are present, however I'm using global menu widget (I should probably mention that) so menus are generated by KDE, not by Firefox.

Comment: That information should be added to the question itself. From whatever I've read on the global menu in KDE, I've not felt it worth trying.